# Open file from input Field

Tags: html, forms, input

I have like 300 .html files and I want to access them with an input field.

The user have IDs that are matching with the .html files. Like:

ID: 324536 
File: 324536.html

Right now I have an .php File with a form. But it really doesn´t matter if it´s an .html or .php file.

Any ideas?

Comment: Explain in brief??

Comment: Isn´t that enough? I can´t export an CMS and have to access some of the content later. I figured I just download it with Curl and access it locallly.